# CSS: flexbox and scroll?

Tags: css, scrollbar, flexbox

My code : (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaQyMo)

CSS:

```
html, body
  height: 100%
  line-height: 1.5

.wrap
  height: 100vh
  display: flex

main
  flex: 1
  display: flex
  @media (max-width: 800px)
    flex-direction: column    

h1
  margin-top: 0

aside
  flex: 1
  background: #f7f7f7 
  overflow-y: hidden 
  height: 100vh
  position: relative

article
  flex: 2
  background: #f0eeee  
  padding: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll

#aside1
    background: tomato
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;

#aside2
    background: #bbb
    position: absolute
    top: 100vh
    transform: translate(0, -50px)
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    transition: all .4s

#aside2.show
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0)

#aside2-head
    padding: 0 .5em
    height: 50px
    background: #bbb
    cursor: pointer
    h1
      text-align: center;

#aside2-content
    padding: 2em
    background: darkblue
    height: 100%
    overflow-y: auto
```

My problems :

- The bottom of the red section (#aside1) is hidden by the "click me" button, here is how I want it to be:

[image: ideal-aside1]

- The bottom of the blue section (#aside2-content) is hidden even if we scroll until the bottom, here is how I want it to be:

[image: ideal-aside2-content]

I can get the result with a fixed height, but this is not a flexible solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Problems: I dont see a navbar , hidden by click me???,

Comment: Forget about the navbar...

Comment: Also i didnt get what you mean by hidden , how do you want it to be?

Comment: I added pictures to show how I want it to be.